# C++11 std::condition_variable - notify_one() not behaving as expected?

Tags: c++11, concurrency, conditional-statements

I don't see this program having any practical usage, but while experimenting with c++ 11 concurrency and conditional_variables I stumbled across something I don't fully understand.

At first I assumed that using `notify_one()` would allow the program below to work. However, in actuality the program just froze after printing one. When I switched over to using `notify_all()` the program did what I wanted it to do (print all natural numbers in order). I am sure this question has been asked in various forms already. But my specific question is where in the [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) did I read wrong.

I assume `notify_one()` should work because of the following statement.

> If any threads are waiting on *this, calling notify_one unblocks one of the waiting threads.

Looking below only one of the threads will be blocked at a given time, correct?

```
class natural_number_printer
{
public:
  void run()
  {
    m_odd_thread = std::thread(
      std::bind(&natural_number_printer::print_odd_natural_numbers, this));
    m_even_thread = std::thread(
      std::bind(&natural_number_printer::print_even_natural_numbers, this));

    m_odd_thread.join();
    m_even_thread.join();
  }

private:
  std::mutex m_mutex;
  std::condition_variable m_condition;

  std::thread m_even_thread;
  std::thread m_odd_thread;

private:
  void print_odd_natural_numbers()
  {
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
      if (i % 2 == 1) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
        m_condition.notify_all();
      } else {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_condition.wait(lock);
      }
    }
  }

  void print_even_natural_numbers()
  {
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
        m_condition.notify_all();
      } else {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_condition.wait(lock);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You have a race condition - if a `notify()` or `notify_all()` occurs and nothing is waiting on the condition, then nothing will be released.  If the thread arrives after the notify, then it will have missed the notification that would have released it, and it'll be stuck there.  I'm not sure why you don't see the problem when `notify_all()` is used, but sometimes that's the nature of a race condition.

Comment: @MichaelBurr By what mechanisms would you synchronize the starting of the two threads? Without producing a deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided code "works" correctly and gets stuck by design. The cause is described in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one#Notes)

> The effects of notify_one()/notify_all() and
>   wait()/wait_for()/wait_until() take place in a single total order, so
>   it's impossible for notify_one() to, for example, be delayed and
>   unblock a thread that started waiting just after the call to
>   notify_one() was made.

The step-by-step logic is

1. The `print_odd_natural_numbers` thread is started
2. The `print_even_natural_numbers` thread is started also.
3. The `m_condition.notify_all();` line of `print_even_natural_numbers` is executed before than the `print_odd_natural_numbers` thread reaches the `m_condition.wait(lock);` line.
4. The `m_condition.wait(lock);` line of `print_odd_natural_numbers` is executed and the thread gets stuck.
5. The `m_condition.wait(lock);` line of `print_even_natural_numbers` is executed and the thread gets stuck also.